# How to get rejected calls without CallLog.Calls.REJECTED_TYPE?

Tags: android

I need to get all incoming calls including missed and rejected. And I have a problem with rejected calls. I want to use `CallLog.Calls.REJECTED_TYPE`, but it’s available since api 24. Now I’m using a constant value 5 for it, but I’ve heard that for some devices `CallLog.Calls.REJECTED_TYPE != 5`. Are there any another solutions to get rejected calls?